# PHP function's alternative in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, transliteration

Lets say we have some 1000 rows that must be transliterated in MySQL database. I have following PHP transliterate function which works well

```
   public static function tlit($str)
{
    $orig = array("ə", "ü", "i", "ö", "ı", "ç", 'ş', "ğ", "Ə", "Ü", "İ", "Ö", "I", "Ç", 'Ş', "Ğ");

    $tlit = array("e", "u", "i", "o", "i", "c", 's', "g", "E", "U", "I", "O", "I", "C", 'S', "G");

    return $textcyr = str_replace($orig, $tlit, $str);
}
```

For letter `ə` we have 2 alternates: `a` and `e`. for example if word is `Əli` I want to get both `Eli` and `Ali` inside results.

For letter `ş` we have 2 alternates: `sh` and `s`. for example if word is `Şəhər` Result will be like:

- Seher
- Sheher
- Sahar
- Shahar

For letter `ç` we have 2 alternates: `ch` and `c`.

I can't figure out how to create MySQL function alternative which will transliterate like this. Any solutions?

Comment: @Naruto I want to switch this function to MySQL:)

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: @heron it means don't fix things that aren't broken - just use the PHP script you already have... After all we're talking about 1000records which will take no more than 30seconds to import via the php script.

Comment: How do you intend to use such a function? Do you just want to have MySQL spit out the possible transiterations for one given input string, or do you want to also be able to use it in a search (something like `SELECT * FROM t WHERE translit(mycol, 'Şəhər');`) *P.S: [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:If_it_ain't_broke,_don't_fix_it)*

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am not an expert, but as a Spanish speaking person I have faced some issues like this in the past.

Do you think you can handle the issue with MySQL Collations? Maybe you can choose a collation from here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html and then MySQL will do the translit for you.

Perhaps it isn't the solution, but it can bring some ideas on how you can search your goal.

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach would be - use application, since MySQL stored code is very limited in such cases. First of all - MySQL doesn't have any (sane) replacement for arrays. Thus, you can't specify anything like "list of symbols". Next, replacement in DBMS may cause many different issues, related to collations. And that may be really painful - to figure out what went wrong in this case.

However, if your symbols lists are always projection 1:1 (so, single symbol will always be replaced by single symbol), then you may "emulate" arrays with plain string. That is - maintain relation between your replacements via string index (so, offset). Using this principle you can write something like:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION TRANSLIT_SYMBOLS(str VARCHAR(255), c_in VARCHAR(255), c_out VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
   DECLARE pos    INT DEFAULT 1;
   DECLARE sym    INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE final  VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
   DECLARE till   INT DEFAULT 0;
   IF CHAR_LENGTH(c_in)!=CHAR_LENGTH(c_out) || !CHAR_LENGTH(c_in) THEN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '80800' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Incompatible or empty transliteration lists';
   END IF;
   SET till = CHAR_LENGTH(str);
   WHILE pos<=till DO
      SET sym = LOCATE(SUBSTR(str, pos, 1), c_in);
      IF sym THEN
         SET final = CONCAT(final, SUBSTR(c_out, sym, 1));
      ELSE
         SET final = CONCAT(final, SUBSTR(str, pos, 1));
      END IF;
      SET pos = pos+1;    
   END WHILE;
   RETURN final;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Here:

- `str` is input string - so inside it replacement would be done
- `c_in` is string, characters of which would be treated as symbols to replace
- `c_out` is string, characters of which would be treated as replacement symbols.

So usage would be

```
mysql> select translit_symbols('foo', 'of', 'ab');
+-------------------------------------+
| translit_symbols('foo', 'of', 'ab') |
+-------------------------------------+
| baa                                 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

About collations - since this function is using direct string offset, it should work properly with multi-byte symbols, but only if corresponding connection & data collation match. I've not tested it in other cases, so it may cause unexpected result if collations are different - but that's again, because MySQL stored function is a poor choice for this case.